# How to ensure private secure editing in vim?

Tags: vimrc, security

I was recently [looking at a another users `.vimrc`](https://github.com/kenorb/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) and noticed that they had settings which we commented as `secure, private editing`; how does one accomplish this, and what do the settings in question mean?

I noticed one of them was `nobackup` which seems to me to mean that you don't create that `~` file that always hangs around.

Note: you may want to port this over to the security stackexchange as well, they could probably use it over there.

Comment: Related: [Simplest way to start Vim in private mode](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6177/simplest-way-to-start-vim-in-private-mode?lq=1)

Comment: Related: [Prevent Vim from recording events for certain filetypes](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/834/prevent-vim-from-recording-events-for-certain-filetypes?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each of those options, do:

```
:help 'option'
```

For example:

```
:help 'nobackup'
```

Comment: Well I know that, but I was just wondering if this is a good complete list of options or if there are other suggestions to this.

Comment: But that's not what you asked.