# How to execute vim when one needs to edit sensitive data?

Tags: security

I keep my passwords in PGP encrypted file. When I need to edit this file, then I first decrypt it(`gpg -d ...`), open the plain-text file in `vim` and make the changes, encrypt the plain-text file(`gpg --output data.gpg --encrypt --recipient ...`) and finally remove the plain-text file. How can I be absolutely sure that `vim` does not store any sensitive data anywhere else than in this plain-text file? I guess I need to disable `viminfo` and it probably it makes sense to disable plugins as well? So if I use `vim -i NONE -u NONE plain-text-file`, then I should be secure?

Comment: Related: [The simplest way to start Vim in private mode](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6177/6590)

Comment: https://github.com/jamessan/vim-gnupg might be useful.

Comment: Perhaps consider using a dedicated password manager instead. Having a plain text file containing your passwords on a hard drive, even for a limited time, seems risky (since the contents of the file will remain on the disc until overwritten).

Comment: @StandardEyre Thanks for referring to [The simplest way to start Vim in private mode](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6177/the-simplest-way-to-start-vim-in-private-mode) question. I finally ended up with `vim -Nu .vimrcprivate` solution. @evilsoup I try to mitigate those risks with full-disk encryption and when I remove the plain-text file, then I always use `shred -u plain-text-file` instead of `rm plain-text-file`.