# Safe configuration for editing pass entries

Tags: vimrc, security

So I use the [Pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) program to store passphrases with gpg. To edit these entries you can use the $EDITOR environment variable. Now, I had set vim to store swap files and backup files with the following commands in my `.vimrc` file:

```
set backupdir=~/.vimtmp//
set directory=~/.vimtmp//
set undodir=~/.vimtmp//
```

Of course this stores my `pass` entries in cleartext, which is bad.  i have tinkered with the ideas of setting my `$EDITOR` variable to `vim -u NONE -i NONE` or just `busybox vi`, but I don't know what the safest alternative is, or if there's even a different vi clone meant for this kind of stuff. there's also a `vim-redact-pass` plugin but I'd rather not use any plugins at all to minimize risks.
What's a reasonably safe way to use vi{m,} to handle `pass` entries?

Comment: Also see: [The simplest way to start Vim in private mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6177/51) – that answer may be a bit outdated though; it should probably also do something with packages/`packpath` now that we have packages to avoid loading any plugins.

Comment: Interesting question. I can't claim to have a complete or authoritative answer, but EDITOR="vim -u NONE -i NONE" disables most of the leaking settings (see https://github.com/zx2c4/password-store/blob/master/contrib/vim/redact_pass.vim). However, it not clear whether having the default `writebackup` value is actually a problem.