# Why is an autocmd using cryptmethod a better way to prevent Vim from recording events than a separate vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, security, encryption

There is [a comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/834/prevent-vim-from-recording-events-for-certain-filetypes/1940#comment1861_1940) by [Carpetsmoker](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/) which suggests a way to [prevent Vim from recording events for certain filetypes](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/834/prevent-vim-from-recording-events-for-certain-filetypes/):

> I would not recommend using a separate vimrc file, for the simple reason that it's so easy to forget. Something like this autocmd: `au BufRead * if &cryptmethod != "" | setlocal nobackup noundofile ... | endif` should do the magic for you, and it's impossible to forget.

I am not sure if I understand how it is suppose to work.

#### Questions:

Do I have to basically start Vim with an option like this: `vim +"set cryptmethod=blowfish"` to trigger the `setlocal nobackup noundofile ...` section of the autocommand from the comment?

Why does Carpetsmoker say that the crytpmethod way is superior to the separate vimrc way?
As I think of it, both

```
vim -u ~/.vimrc-incognito
```

and

```
vim +"set cryptmethod=blowfish"
```

are equally easy to forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the original question was asking about how to prevent leakage of sensitive information *every time* certain filetypes are edited.

The essential point that @Carpetsmoker was trying to make is that this feature should be automatic, because anything manual is easy to forget.

Note that he wrote: "***Something like*** this autocmd" (emphasis mine), so this code isn't necessarily supposed to be a full answer. I *think* he may have misremembered the encryption options slightly, and meant to check `'key'`, which is set if and only if encryption is being used, rather than `'cryptmethod'`, which is set by default to `'zip'`*. Seeing as the original question was about filetypes though, the following might have been a simpler illustration of his concept:

```
au BufRead *.[sensitive filetype] setlocal nobackup noundofile ...
```

To use your examples, he's *not* suggesting you should use:

```
vim +"set cryptmethod=blowfish"
```

instead of

```
vim -u ~/.vimrc-incognito
```

He's suggesting you should configure Vim is such a way that you can use:

```
# automatic, impossible to forget
vim filename.[sensitive filetype]
```

instead of:

```
# manual, easy to forget
vim -u ~/.vimrc-incognito filename.[sensitive filetype]
```

...which is an obvious improvement.

None of this is really relevant to what you are trying to do, however, which is specifically to create a feature that is *not* limited to certain filetypes and which *does* need to be turned on manually.

<sub>* and I suspect even this wouldn't actually work well, as I don't *think* this autocmd would fire when setting the key with `:X` — I haven't tested this, though.</sub>